# Two NICs and routing between the interfaces

Tags: networking, server, dns

I am having a problem with an Ubuntu server running two NICs on two different subnets androuting between them.  We are running a Nginx server as a reverse proxy with a public subnet and private subnet.

We are running ubuntu server 15.04.

Here’s the setup :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:88:6e:91
          inet addr:89.21.20.14  Bcast:89.21.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe88:6e91/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:89152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1729 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5552124 (5.5 MB)  TX bytes:286442 (286.4 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:88:16:0b
          inet addr:10.150.200.50  Bcast:10.150.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe88:160b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:53395 (53.3 KB)  TX bytes:1908 (1.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:12960 (12.9 KB)  TX bytes:12960 (12.9 KB)
```

I have the gateway on eth0.

When I try and ping 89.21.20.14 from a server on 10.150.200.xx subnet it isn’t working and I cannot communicate with it.  The traffic is hitting eth0 as I can see from

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 proto \\icmp
```

I have also tried to do the same thing going from a server in 89.21.20.xx and access/ping 10.150.200.50 but that isn’t going through either.  When running the tcpdump I can see the pings hitting eth1

Problem is that we have websites running on the private subnet web servers and they reference domains that point to the public IPs on 89.21.20.xx and therefore cannot communicate with the sites/applications.

I’m thinking it’s some kind of routing issue but not too sure of where to start?

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         89.21.24.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.150.200.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
89.21.20.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0



Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         89.21.20.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.150.200.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Post `route`command output.

Comment: @JohnFox add that as an [*edit to your question*](http://askubuntu.com/posts/696781/edit) not as a comment.  Also, read my answer, and clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve (nginx as a reverse proxy is NOT a router, and you will only be able to ping `eth1` from things that are connected to that private subnet on `eth1`).  Also explain why this is tagged as 'nginx'

Answer (score 2):

You state in comments that you don't want subnet traversal.  You've already got this, then, with the not being able to reach `eth0` from `eth1` and vice versa, so your issue is already resolved.

If you have some other question, though, you need to be more specific with what you're asking.  (The reverse proxying happens transparently, you won't be able to reach `eth0` from `eth1` or vice versa, not without going through `nginx` on the reverse proxy server).

---

> The below is kept for historical reasons.

I'm curious why this is tagged [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx), because this is not an NGINX issue, it's a case of you trying to go from inside (`eth1` and the internal subnet) to outside (`eth0`, and the public Internet) without a router (or a system configured as a router) in place or a rule to let your 'server' act as a proxy from inside->out (which is NOT a reverse proxy).

NGINX is not a proxy or router.  A reverse proxy will say "OK, so send this request to the backend, abc."  Then, it'll say "ABC: Send me the response", which will send the initial request made from outside to the internal server.  That then gets you the response from backend 'abc' at the nginx server.  That is returned by nginx to the requesting client.

A reverse proxy also only works outside -> in.  This diagram shows basically how that looks from outside going in:

[image: Hastily Drawn Diagram by Thomas W.]

The reverse path works, but only because the Reverse Proxy System (nginx) is waiting for response from the backends, and then hands that data back to the Web Browser or remote client making the request for information and expecting a response back.

The reverse path, however, does NOT permit you to go from `eth1` on the Reverse Proxy to `eth0` on the Reverse Proxy via the Remote Proxy system - that's not how IP routing works, and to achieve what you're looking to achieve, you need a *real* router in place that can handle network traversal from the Internal IPs to the outside, and then back to the Public IP address of `eth0` on the reverse proxy box, so it'd look like this:

[image: the router way, another diagram by Thomas W.]

The data traversal here, then, would be from the internal boxes, through the router box they're connected to, out to the Internet, and then from the Internet back to your `eth0` box. (The most basic way of explaining this of course).

However, your Reverse Proxy box does ***not*** double as a router, so it doesn't work in the way you're thinking it does.

---

On another note:

You don't get to ping from internal (which goes to `eth1`) to `eth0` directly, which is on a ***completely different subnet*** unless you go through an actual router and go outside then back in.  Unless you set up your server that also has nginx on it to be a router, which from your comments appears to not be the case.  So, this "not able to ping across interfaces and subnets" is **expected behavior**.

Comment: We do have a router on the network that isnt the ubuntu server and this is providing the gateway.  Yes, the nginx part is a bit misleading and irelevant.  The idea behind having the two nics is that the public IP is the only bit that is accessible and the second nic on the private subnet is used to direct the traffic over to the web servers on the private lan.

Comment: I'm ok with the Nginx Reverse Proxy side of things.  I'm with you on that explanation.

Comment: @JohnFox Then why are you trying to ping `eth0` from the internal servers?  Those internal servers aren't connected to a router, are they?  If they are, then you need your router / firewall to be able to handle routing of requests to the public IP address assigned to `eth0` on the Reverse Proxy box.  You should also consider that an ***internal*** range should never be trying to reach the public IP address on `eth0` or have to.  I believe what you're trying to achieve is an Impossible Situation (TM) as a result of not understanding networking limitations and network restrictions/rules.

Comment: ... The same network restrictions apply here too, for the other direction, from `eth0` to `eth1` - you can't ping via those interfaces to the other interface because you don't have routing rules to handle PublicIP -> PrivateIP.  A router wouldn't be able to help you here either.

Comment: The internal servers are connected to the router and have external access (via NAT).  These are web servers that need to make calls to external services.  We have applications that call themselves via their domain names (that go to the public IP addresses) and currently dont work.

Comment: We currently have routing behind the firewall between the different subnets but ultimately we want only the only way to acces our web applications is via subnet (eth0) and have no routing between subnets (hence the 2nd NIC in the server onto the private LAN).  Thanks for your assitance so far

Comment: @JohnFox then you have to set up ACLs on the Firewall.  But the Public IPs can't be reached from your internal subnet already, so it looks like this isolation si already complete.  (You do need your Reverse Proxy box to be on both Public and Private in order to do reverse proxying, however, so it looks like you're already done with this)

Comment: We have it working as we need to on a windows setup but just not on the linux setup we have above (so don't think we need anything reconfigured oon the ACLs on the router/firewall).  I appreciate it's an odd situation but we have servers on both subnets that we need to be able to communivcate with.  Ideally we do not want anything on the public subnet to access the private subnet (incase things get compromised) but we do have servers on there (for the time being).  We want to moved all of these servers onto the provate subnet and only have the public IPs of the reverse proxys visible

Comment: @JohnFox Your purpose here is ambiguous and our goal is currently impossible.  Are you trying to get the internal servers to be able to ping eth0 on the reverse proxy from eth1 / internal net?  If so you can't since they aren't physically on the same connection nor the same subnet.  So unless you are just not explaining this clearly (draw a diagram!) I don't think we can help you any further... the issue you face is cause of Impossible Situation because Working As Intended...